# Xamarin SQLite-net-pcl UWP error

Tags: android, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am trying to build a xamarin forms application with a local db. I am following the instructions https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/, but when it comes to install the nuget package in the UWP project, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages\'.           0

I don't have that folder, and I don't know what is supposed to be there. With the android project it successfully installed the packaged.
How can I get around this? Or, in alternative, what can I use to have a local db shared code between my different target platforms?

Comment: I think that doc may be outdated. There is now an SQLite for UWP extension for Visual Studio that you can load into the VS extensions and then reference from your UWP app. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: This did the trick: Update-Package -Reinstall -Safe -ProjectName MyProject.UWP
After that I was able to add that nugget package. @jgoldberger But, would that be compatible with Xamarin Forms?

Comment: it is compatible with xamarin.uwp the nuget package provide the UWP interface. I think you can use it.